# Eclipse Egit new commit overwrite the last commit

Tags: git, egit, eclipse-mars

when i commit to the branch ,i just lost my last commit.It just disappeared in git log.I work well when i use the commandline to commit.Not in the Egit.My eclipse version is j2ee Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1).Anyone for help?

Comment: Did you return to the bash and type `git status` to see what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

> I just lost my last commit.It just disappeared in git log

You don't "lose" commits in a git repo, at least not right away:  switch to command-line and do a [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog): you will see your "lost" commit there.